# How may I create this array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a query from database that returns an array of values and puts into `$history array`.
Each value have the `course_id`, `unit_id` and the `time_stamp`.

I'd like to have another array with the `course_id` and the respective `unit_ids`.

The `course_id` has to have the latest `time_stamp` and each `unit_id` has to have it's own `time_stamp`.

It's also needed to have max 4 units in each course `array`.

(Luckly the `$history` array from DB is already `ORDER BY time_stamp DESC` so I guess I only need to get the first `time_stamp` for the course and the first 4 units of each course).

So what I need is:

```
courseListArray:
  array[0]:
  course_id: closest time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
  array[1]:
  course_id: closest time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
    unit_id: time_stamp
```

Follow a sample of the DB query:

```
array(6) { ["course_id"]=> string(4) "2968" [0]=> string(4) "2968" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "3002" [1]=> string(4) "3002" ["time_stamp"]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:54:11.000000" [2]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:54:11.000000" } 

array(6) { ["course_id"]=> string(4) "2968" [0]=> string(4) "2968" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "3006" [1]=> string(4) "3006" ["time_stamp"]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:41:54.000000" [2]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:41:54.000000" } 

array(6) { ["course_id"]=> string(4) "2740" [0]=> string(4) "2740" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "2982" [1]=> string(4) "2982" ["time_stamp"]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:20:01.000000" [2]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:20:01.000000" } 

array(6) { ["course_id"]=> string(4) "3017" [0]=> string(4) "3017" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "3012" [1]=> string(4) "3012" ["time_stamp"]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:12:19.000000" [2]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:12:19.000000" }
```

I've tried the code below, but it didn't work as expected, because the `array keys` was not filling correct.

```
foreach ($history as $data) {
    if (!array_key_exists($data['course_id'], $courseList)) {
        array_push($courseList, $data['course_id']);
        $courseList[$data['course_id']] = array();
    }

    if (count($courseList[$data['course_id']]) <= 4) {
        array_push($courseList[$data['course_id']], $data['unit_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `$courseList` supposed to be an index or associative array? `array_push` is for indexed arrays, but `$courseList[$data['course_id']]` accesses it as an associative array. Your diagram looks like an indexed array.

Comment: You can't have multiple `unit_id` keys in the same array, since array keys must be unique. You should make `unit_id` an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up indexed and associative arrays. You should make `$course_array` an associative array whose key is the `course_id`. The value should then be a sub-array that contains all the rows for that course ID.

```
foreach ($history as $data) {
    $cid = $data['course_id'];
    if (!isset($courseArray[$cid])) {
        $courseArray[$cid] = array();
    }
    $courseArray[$cid][$data['unit_id']] = $data['time_stamp'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I don't know PHP well. Would you mind telling me how to place the `unit_id` as key and `time_stamp` the value inside the `units` array as you did with the `course time_stamp?`

Comment: I"ve tried: `$courseArray[$cid]['units'][] = array($data['unit_id'] => $data['time_stamp']);` but it gets me a index: `array(2) { ["time_stamp"]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:54:11.000000" ["units"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [3002]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:54:11.000000" } [1]=> array(1) { [3006]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:41:54.000000" } } } `

Comment: I've changed the answer to do that.

Comment: I can't believe how you made it looks so simple. I guess I just need to practice more. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
foreach ($history as $data) {
    if (!array_key_exists('course'.$data['course_id'], $courseList)) {
        array_push($courseList, $data['course_id']);

        $courseList['course'.$data['course_id']] = array();
        $courseList['course'.$data['course_id']]['units'] = array();
        $courseList['course'.$data['course_id']]['course'] = [$data['course_id'] => $data['time_stamp']];
    }

    if (count($courseList['course'.$data['course_id']]['units']) <= 4) {
        array_push($courseList['course'.$data['course_id']]['units'], [$data['unit_id'] => $data['time_stamp']]);
    }
}

foreach ($courseList as $key => $course) {
    if (!is_numeric($key)) {
        var_dump($course);
        echo '<BR><BR>';
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
array(2) { ["units"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [3002]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:54:11.000000" } [1]=> array(1) { [3006]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:41:54.000000" } } ["course"]=> array(1) { [2968]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 14:54:11.000000" } } 

array(2) { ["units"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [2982]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:20:01.000000" } } ["course"]=> array(1) { [2740]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:20:01.000000" } } 

array(2) { ["units"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [3012]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:12:19.000000" } } ["course"]=> array(1) { [3017]=> string(26) "2016-06-10 13:12:19.000000" } }
```

EDIT:

Barmar's answer is way better.

Comment: You're making the same mistake as the question, using `array_push` on an associative array.

Comment: @Barmar, why can't I do it here?

Comment: @Barmar, I guess that I need to go that way because I don't have any other parameter (as I know of), to check if the `course id` is already there.